# How to remove dotted outlines on links, buttons, inputs, textareas and buttons

Tags: css, outline

How can I remove these ugly outline on every element in FireFox? I also want to know how to remove the ugly outline in Google Chrom on inputs and textareas. As you can see I used any possible attribute I know. Its still there (the dotted outline in FF and the outline on inputs etc in Chrome).

```
*:active,
*:focus,
*:visited,
*::active,
*::focus,
*::visited,
input:active,
input:focus,
input:visited,
input::active,
input::focus,
input::visited,
textarea:active,
textarea:focus,
textarea:visited,
textarea::active,
textarea::focus,
textarea::visited,
a:active,
a:focus,
a:visited,
a::active,
a::focus,
a::visited
{
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -webkit-tap-highlight: none;
    -webkit-focus-ring-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-focus-ring-color: transparent;
    -webkit-focus-ring-color: none;
    outline: 0;
    outline: none;
}
*:-moz-focus-inner,
*::-moz-focus-inner,
input:-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner,
textarea:-moz-focus-inner,
textarea::-moz-focus-inner,
a:-moz-focus-inner,
a::-moz-focus-inner
{
    border-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `appearance` property:

```
-webkit-appearance: value;
-moz-appearance:    value;
appearance:         value;
```

for more info: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by myself. The problem is that the elements doesnt inherit my values. I needed to set these thing right into the class.